# return a file id from a function c++

Tags: c++, types

I want to return a file id from a function. What type should my function be?

Here is a test "main" which performs very similarly to the desired function.

```
    // this c++ code tests statements
//    #include </home/steve/cpincludes>
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){                   //   replace this line with type getid(){
const char* cname ="test.txt";
string line;
std::string name=cname;
std::ifstream is;
cout << cname <<"   "<< name <<'\n';

is.open(name.c_str(),ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);

while ( getline (is,line) ) { //test read
  cout << line << '\n';    }
return (0);}                  //   replace this line with return (is) ;}
```

Comment: you're reading from stream, so you can return stream

Comment: @Lashane you can't return a `std::ifstream` object; it's not copyable.

Comment: @sdzivanovich you can return pointer

Comment: @Lashane returning a pointer to a local object? definitely don't want to do that

Comment: @sdzivanovich allocate it via new and return pointer

Comment: @Lashane maybe you should have specified all of that in your original comment ;)

Comment: @sdzivanovich maybe, but I've decided just to give hint in comments without going in deep discussion or giving full answer

Comment: Since C++11, `ifstream` is movable, so you *can* return it from a function.

Comment: So my question stands. How does one accomplish return of either the file id or the pointer. Note that what I really want is access to the string of file data in the main program and the class of which the above is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was **under** thinking the problem. This code goes in the user interface function, but I only open the file there to check existence.The simple answer is

```
ifstream my_file("test.txt");
if (my_file) cout << "file exists";
else cout << "file not found";
```

(properly re-structured of course) Then I will return the file name to main. Opening and reading the file in main is a much better answer as it takes it out of the user interface from where it doesn't belong anyway. It also makes the file data string available to pass to other processing functions, as was the objective.

Answer (score 1):

As of C++11 you can move concrete iostreams:

```
std::ifstream foo(std::string const& path)
{
  std::ifstream stream{path};
  // Do whatever      
  return stream;
}
```

This will work with libc++ or VS > 2010, but not libstdc++ (until the next version of libstdc++ bundled with gcc 5.0 is released).

If your library does not support moving streams, you will have to use a pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream> foo(std::string const& path)
{
  auto stream = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(path);
  // Do whatever      
  return stream;
}
```

or pass the stream as a reference

```
void foo(std::ifstream& stream)
{
  // Do whatever      
}
```